# How to check if all the kafka servers received a message through cmd line

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka

I have started the zookeeper server, then the kafka servers in 2 instances. Created a topic with `--partitions 1 --replication-factor 2`

And then ran `kafka-console-producer.sh` and passed a message 'hello world'

I cld see the 'hello world' message when i run `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic topicName --from-beginning`

But how do i make sure that all the kafka servers received that message. what's the command for it

Comment: What do you think `datetime2(0)=` is going to do for you here? Both of those don't make much syntactic sense and look like they can be removed entirely, but it's not clear why they're there in the first place.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to ask something completely different. If you have a new question, just go ahead and ask it on a new page.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Note that I've rolled back an edit which turned this into a completely different question. Your comment is a good one for the other question, if the OP asks it on a new page.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was trying to convert the resulting date field to timestamp by using datetime2(0)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Instead of that I can simply remove the `cast(getdate() to date)` and use `getdate()` directly I believe

Comment: @manket If you want to discuss your SQL Server question, please click "Ask Question" and add all the details on a new page. This page is a question about Apache Kafka.